# how to switch a tensor in theano to numpy.array

Tags: numpy, theano

I have a tensor T (shape:300) and a array A(shape:300), what i want to do is combine them into a new array [T,A] with the shape (600). I tried the solutiona below:

1 combine directly,use function: np.concatenate((T,A)), the result is:zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

2 switch one type to another, try to switch the T to the type of numpy.array: i use: a=np.array(T), but when print a.shape, it is (), nothing in the bracket.

Besides, when i print T.shape and A.shape, T.shape is ([300]) and A.shape is (300,)what is the difference?

Comment: Do you want to work in Theano or numpy? Decide that first. You can't use operations from the numpy namespace directly on Theano tensors. Arrays of shape `300,` are not zero-dimensional. This error message is either due to the fact that you are concatenating Theano tensors using numpy, or their content is not what you expect. So maybe check the content of them first. Please also write a FULLY copy+pasteable example which we can copy + paste into an IPython to help debug.

Comment: So how can i switch numpy.array to theano.tensor  and conversely?

Comment: Please make an example that reproduces your error. Your question is difficult to answer without context. One doesn't usually "switch" from one to the other. Numpy arrays become entries and results of Theano functions as well as shared variables. Theano functions are constructed entirely from symbolic objects.

Answer (score -2):

when we want to get a numpy.array from a tensor T, it can be done by T.eval(), i tried a lot and found this way. But i haven't found the way switched from numpy.array to tensor T yet.  Anyone can help?